# How to catch remove event in react-select when removing item from selected?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

first of all, thanks for awesome work. It makes a lot easier for me. Then here i want to catch remove event, how can I do that? I read the documentation and could not find remove event

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think they have an event for that. They just have the `onChange`.

So, to detect if some option was removed, you would have to compare the current state with the new values the `onChange` emitted.

Example:

```js
handleOnChange(value) {
  let difference = this.state.selected.filter(x => !value.includes(x)); // calculates diff
  console.log('Removed: ', difference);                         // prints array of removed

  this.setState({ selected: value });
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        multi={this.state.multi}
        options={this.state.options}
        onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.selected}
        showNewOptionAtTop={false}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/7ymwokxoyq

Comment: whoa, thanks didn't think that it would work this way.

Comment: is it possible to give argument for `loadOptions` ? Let's say i got 4 react-select components and each of them has a different endpoint. Currently, I put 4 different loadOptions function to them. Is it possible?

Comment: thanks, for me I wanted the array without the difference, not the difference itself, so I just removed the !, like this -> let difference = this.state.selected.filter(x => value.includes(x));

Answer (score 6):

React Select exposes a variety of eventListeners to you via props. The **onchange** function prop now has the following signature. (value: ValueType, action: ActionType).

Accordingly, you can get these events:
**select-option**, **deselect-option**, **remove-value**, **pop-value**, **set-value**, **clear**, **create-option**, through which you can handle creation and deletion.

Please refer to [documentation](https://react-select.com/advanced)

Answer (score 1):

They don't have any event for that. I was facing the same problem but in my case, I was needing both the `added` and `removed` item. In case someone wants the both values

```
import 'difference' from 'lodash/difference'
this.currentTags = []
handleChange = (options) => {
    const optionsValue = options.map(({ value }) => value)
    if (this.currentTags.length < options.length) {
      const addedElement = difference(optionsValue, this.currentTags)[0]
      this.currentTags.push(addedElement)
      console.log("addedElement",addedElement)
      //call custom add event here
    }
    else {
      let removedElement = difference(this.currentTags, optionsValue)[0]
      console.log("removedElement", removedElement)
      // call custom removed event here
      let index = this.currentTags.indexOf(removedElement)
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.currentTags.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code of snippet is working for me to know if any item is removed
I am calling handle change function on onChange event in reat-select

```
const [selectedGroups, setSelectedGroups] = useState([]);
const handleChange = (value) => {

const diifer = value.length <= selectedGroups.length;
if(diifer){
// item is removed 
}
var arr = value.map((object) => object.value);
setSelectedGroups(arr);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

They have a parameter on onChange Event gives us two things

1. newValue
2. actionMeta

actionMeta looks like this

{
"action": "remove-value",
"removedValue": {
"value": "bb1e0dff-084e-4c2d-a5a7-0ba485bd2954",
"label": "Example label"
},
"name": "Example name"
}